Can one define an induced ordinary category from an enriched one?
I'm curious about Wikipedia's definition of an enriched category. An enriched category $\mathcal{C}$ over a monoidal category $\mathcal M$ is said to contain

an object $\mathcal C(a, b)$ of $M$ for every pair of objects $a, b$ in $\mathcal C$, used to define an arrow $f:a \to b$ in $\mathcal C$ as an arrow $f : I \to \mathcal C$ in $\mathcal M$.

The "used to define an arrow..." part is different from what I've seen elsewhere. Perhaps this is only meant to be suggestive, but it got me wondering: Can we define an "induced ordinary category" $\mathcal C'$ from a given $\mathcal M$-enriched category $\mathcal C$?
Consider the following approach. For each object $a, b$ in $\mathcal C$, we define the set $\hom'(a, b)$ to be the set of all $\mathcal M$-morphisms from $I$ to $\hom(a, b)$. Let $f \in \hom'(a, b)$ and $g \in \hom'(b, c)$. We define the composition $g \circ' f$ as the $\mathcal M$ morphism
$$I \xrightarrow{\lambda^{-1}} I \otimes I \xrightarrow{g \otimes f} \hom(b, c) \otimes hom(a, b) \xrightarrow{\circ_{abc}} \hom(a, c). $$
Here $\lambda$ is the canonical isomorphism taking $I \otimes M \to M$. With this definition, $g \circ' f \in \hom'(a, c)$, so this looks promising.
But one problem is whether (e.g.) $f \circ' \text{id}_a = f$. I'm not seeing that this follows from the diagrams defining the properties of $\text{id}_a$ in enriched categories. But it also looks like there might be some solution to this, e.g., maybe $f\circ'\text{id}_a\simeq f$ in some sense. Is there a way to fix this definition so that $\mathcal C'$ really is a category?

That does give a category, the identity you're wondering does hold up to equality. This category goes under the name "underlying category". You can find more about it on, e.g. Riehl's Categorical Homotopy Theory.

Thanks for the tip and reference. I was eventually able to see why $f \circ' \text{id}_a = f$. The key ingredient I was missing earlier was the fact that the left and right unit morphisms $I \otimes a \to a$ and $a \otimes I \to a$ are natural transformations, and the diagrams related to this.
